# Deleted Properties.Resources in VisualStudio

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I accidentally deleted the Properties.Resources of my project. I have all the code of this part in Backup, but I'm unable to restore it! VisualStudio does not give me an option to add another or override another version from TFS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I accidentally deleted the Properties.Resources of my project.

That means you deleted from your local mapping and obviously not from TFS. In that case, another solution would be:

> Delete your existing workspace which will unlink the current mapping.
>
> Create a new workspace -> map it to a new /path/folder in your local
>
> Get latest from TFS

That way you will have everything afresh from your TFS along with Properties.Resources of your project. If you had any changes (code changes) with your earlier mapping; you can just merge them.